# Adding td element to next tr of rowspan td

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have below html,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td rowspan="2">$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to generate below html using jsoup,

```
<tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td rowspan="2">$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
```

I have currenty written this piece of code through which i can get the rowspan cell and its associated td index

```
final Elements rows = table.select("tr");

      int rowspanCount=0;
      String rowspanString ="";
      for(Element row : rows){
          int rowspanIndex = 0;
          for(Element cell: row.select("td")){
              rowspanIndex++;
              if(cell.hasAttr("rowspan")){
                  rowspanCount = Integer.parseInt(cell.attr("rowspan"));

                  rowspanString = cell.ownText();

                  cell.removeAttr("rowspan");
              }
          }
      }
```

Comment: I am trying from last 1 hour.. Can you please help me out

Comment: I have edited the question with the code that i have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Possible HINT: For condition,

```
cell.hasAttr("rowspan")
```

Get row-index, like;

```
int index = row.getIndex();
```

and then get next Row by index+1, like;

```
Element eRow = rows.get(index+1);
```

then append td-Element to this row, this would be your next row to rowspan-row.

Comment: getIndex is not available in Jsoup.

Answer (score 0):

You can append this row simply with this code:

```
Elements rows = table.select("tr > td[rowspan=2]");

for (Element row : rows) {
    row.parent().nextElementSibling().append("<td>$50</td>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After coding everything, I found the solution. Below is the code,

```
for (Element row : rows) {
        int cellIndex = -1;
        if(row.select("td").hasAttr("rowspan")){
            for (Element cell : row.select("td")) {
                cellIndex++;
                if (cell.hasAttr("rowspan")) {
                    rowspanCount = Integer.parseInt(cell.attr("rowspan"));
                    cell.removeAttr("rowspan");

                    Element copyRow = row;

                    for (int i = rowspanCount; i > 1; i--) {
                        nextRow = copyRow.nextElementSibling();
                        Element cellCopy = cell.clone();
                        Element childTd = nextRow.child(cellIndex);
                        childTd.after(cellCopy);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

It duplicates the rowspan cell to all the following rows that should contain it. As well removes the attribute rowspan for removing any further discrepancy.

Comment: Look at my solution, is much simpler :)